# How to sum the value only once in react redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to know in my scenario: After receiving props, the function gets called in the `compoentdidupdate` method, in which am summing up the amount if `id` is same, But it keeps on adding the values multiple times on load. how to resolve this.

```
class Data extends React.PureComponent{
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
   total: "";
 }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.callFetch();
}
callFetch(){
  this.props.dispatch(getData("all"));
 this.props.dispatch(newData("new"));  
}
componentDidUpdate(){
  const { alldata, newdata } = this.props.query;
  const obj =[...alldata, ...newdata];
  const result=[];
 if(obj.length > 0) {
  obj.forEach(function (o) {
      var existing = result.filter(function (i) { return i.id=== o.id})[0];
      if (!existing)
        result.push(o);
      else
        existing.amount+= o.amount;
    });
   this.setState({total: result})
  }
}

render(){
 return(
   this.state.total.length > 0 ?
   this.state.total.map(e=>{
     <div>price:{e.amount}</div>
   }) : ""
 )
}
```

props am receiving is below, but in output am receiving 1200, and keeps on increasing,

```
alldata= [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 200
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 400
}]

newdata= [{
 id: "1",
amount: 400
}]
```

expected output:

```
price: 600
price: 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @miyavv Have a look at the below piece of code. Comparing prevProps and current props should help. It is general technique used in reactjs to solve non-needed runs in componentDidUpdate.

```
class Data extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      total: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.callFetch();
  }
  callFetch() {
    this.props.dispatch(getData("all"));
    this.props.dispatch(newData("new"));
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { alldata, newdata } = this.props.query;
    const obj = [...alldata, ...newdata];
    const result = [];
    // new Line added
    const { alldata: prevAllData, newdata: prevNewData } = prevProps.query;
    if (prevAllData !== alldata || prevNewData !== newdata) {
      if (obj.length > 0) {
        obj.forEach(function(o) {
          var existing = result.filter(function(i) {
            return i.id === o.id;
          })[0];
          if (!existing) result.push(o);
          else existing.amount += o.amount;
        });
        this.setState({ total: result });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.total.length > 0
      ? this.state.total.map(e => {
          <div>price:{e.amount}</div>;
        })
      : "";
  }
}
```

Let me know if it helps !!. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you are dispatching two actions which will result to call componentDidUpdate multiple times. And in your componentDidUpdate method there’s no conditioning telling that your data is already fetched.
You could call only one action that will further dispatch two actions you are dispatching in callFetch method. You could also keep a flag which will tell whether the data is yet fetched or not.

If you are using redux-thunk, than it can be easily achieved. You can define one action which will be dispatched in callFetch method. And in your newly defined action you can dispatch your mentioned two actions.